# apply() Method in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, apply

anyone here know what is actually done by these codes below? I got confused that they produces different result on 'data1'.

Here is the first code:

```
def norm_by_data2(x):
    # x is a DataFrame of group values
    x['data1'] /= x['data2'].sum()
    return x

print(df, "\n")
print(df.groupby('key').apply(norm_by_data2), "\n")
```

Here is the second code:

```
pd.Series(df['data1'] / df['data2'].sum(), name='data1')
```

Output of first code:

```
# How the DataFrame looks like
  key  data1  data2
0   A      0      5
1   B      1      0
2   C      2      3
3   A      3      3
4   B      4      7
5   C      5      9 

  key     data1  data2
0   A  0.000000      5
1   B  0.142857      0
2   C  0.166667      3
3   A  0.375000      3
4   B  0.571429      7
5   C  0.416667      9
```

Output of second code:

```
0    0.000000
1    0.037037
2    0.074074
3    0.111111
4    0.148148
5    0.185185
Name: data1, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First version works with groups so it calculate `sum()` for elements in groups

```
x['data2'].sum() # x is a DataFrame of group values
```

Elements in group `A` use sum `8` (5+3)
Elements in group `B` use sum `7` (0+7)
Elements in group `C` use sum `12` (3+9)

```
A 0/8  = 0.000000
B 1/7  = 0.142857 
C 2/12 = 0.166667 
A 3/8  = 0.375000
B 4/7  = 0.571429
C 5/12 = 0.416667
```

Second version calculate `sum()` for all elements `27` (5+0+3+3+7+9)

```
A 0/27 = 0.000000
B 1/27 = 0.037037
C 2/27 = 0.074074
A 3/27 = 0.111111
B 4/27 = 0.148148
C 5/27 = 0.185185
```

If you use `print(x['data2'].sum())` then you should see it.